# Android - access fragment view from fragment container programatically

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-coordinatorlayout

In MainActivity's `onCreate`, I replaced the `FrameLayout` fragment container in its xml layout with a `DragSelectRecyclerView` in MainFragment's xml layout using `FragmentManager`. The following code shows this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, new MainFragment())
            .commit();
}
```

MainActivity's xml:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.gra.app.activities.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior=".utilities.AppBarLayoutBackgroundAlphaBehavior">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

MainFragment's xml:

```
<com.afollestad.dragselectrecyclerview.DragSelectRecyclerView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
app:dsrv_autoScrollEnabled="true"
app:dsrv_autoScrollHotspotHeight="56dp"
tools:context="com.gra.app.fragments.MainFragment" />
```

Is there any way to programmatically access an instance of `DragSelectRecyclerView` through `FrameLayout`?

The reason for this is I need to make the `AppBarLayout` inside MainActivity's xml dependent on MainFragment's `DragSelectRecyclerView` so I can fade the `AppBarLayout` in/out based on

`DragSelectRecyclerView.getVerticalScrollbarPosition()`

through

```
CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<AppBarLayout>
```

Is this possible or should I just move the `DragSelectRecyclerView` inside MainActivity's xml?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to have a public method in MainFragment -

```
public float getVerticalScrollbarPosition(){
    return DragSelectRecyclerView.getVerticalScrollbarPosition();
}
```

Update MainActivity's onCreate method to this -

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MainFragment mainFragment = new MainFragment();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, mainFragment)
            .commit();
}
```

Now within the MainActivity, you can access the method anywhere to get the value and fade the AppBarLayout in/out accordingly -

```
mainFragment.getVerticalScrollbarPosition();
```

This is how the communication between fragments and activity should be handled - https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity

Answer (score 2):

You could set the fragment directly in the xml layout of the main activity like

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment android:id="@+id/fragment"
          android:name="some.package.MainFragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And then get the instance of DragSelectRecyclerView in the onCreate method of your activity by

```
DragSelectRecyclerView recyclerView = (DragSelectRecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
```

---

Or you just set the DragSelectRecyclerView from your Fragment into your Activity:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    DragSelectRecyclerView dragSelectRecyclerView = (DragSelectRecyclerView) getView().findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    Activity activity = getActivity();
    if (activity != null && activity instanceof MainActivity) {
        ((MainActivity) activity).setDragSelectRecyclerView(dragSelectRecyclerView);
    }
}
```

In both cases make sure you reset the variable after you fragment is gone.

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    Activity activity = getActivity();
    if (activity != null && activity instanceof MainActivity) {
        ((MainActivity) activity).setDragSelectRecyclerView(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: without the FrameLayout as a fragment container how would I switch from one fragment to the next?

Comment: I've decided to handle the toolbar animations manually inside my fragments because if I still go with using CoordinatorLayout.Behavior, I would need to have a CoordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout and Toolbar for each fragment. I wanted to keep things modular and just have the activity handle the Toolbar, so I'm sticking with using the FrameLayout to act as a fragment container. Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

you can try setting a `tag` in the fragment transaction and then retrieve the fragment and its view by the `tag` you set during the transaction.

you can do it like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, new MainFragment(),"tag")     //Adding tag here
            .commit();
}
```

and then later you can retreive the recyclerview inside that fragment by:

```
    View fragmentView = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("tag").getView();
DragSelectRecyclerView recyclerView = (DragSelectRecyclerView)fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView) //use the view
```

but `View fragmentView = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("tag").getView();`  may return null based on the state of the fragment's state. so you need to look out for that.